# Ways to speed up CVS operations?

Tags: cvs

I am working with a codebase managed by CVS.  But CVS operations are getting slower and slower.  For example, creating a new branch is painful, taking nearly an hour.  (By comparison, I can check out a fresh copy of an existing tag in about 8 minutes.)

What steps could we take to speed up CVS?

This is a project with CVS history dating back 14 years. We have discussed migrating to svn or git, but cannot easily make a such a change, because
we have in-house development tools that rely heavily on CVS.

Comment: Not an answer, but what I have done with our 13 year old codebase at work is to turn my CVS working copy into a git repo. I do all my (cheap) branching/merging and coding there and "push" to CVS when I am done with a feature. I also "pull" from CVS periodically so I am in sync with the CVS repository. It's a stopgap measure but alleviates some of the pain of using CVS with such a large and old repository.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a CVS branch means re-writing the entire history of every file you tag.  This is a LOT of disk activity and probably very random. Putting the repository onto a Flash drive *might* help.

To see if it'll help you need to see if your server is CPU or disk bound during the 'branch' operation.

As for your issue with CVS based tools looking at the database. In git there is a command called `git-cvsserver` that provides a server process that CVS clients can do simple operations from (NOT branch) see: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsserver

Comment: I will look at CPU vs disk usage, to try to find the main culprit.  Thanks.  `git-cvsserver` is not really an option, because we rely heavily on tagging and branching.